# How to combine multidimensional PHP array keys by identifying key and sum the values

Tags: php, arrays, sum

Below is a single array consisting of child arrays. Each child is a result set on a database
for a particular event and they are grouped by that using the `[event_id]` field. I want to 
sum the points for customers and then once thats done, traverse the array and add a new element
called `[point_total]` to each child array. Matching arrays based on `[customer_id]` would have their points totaled and then added to each array containing that customer id. I'm not sure if this is possible to do all at one or if I must run over the array a second time after the points are totaled to add a total_points field for the customers.

Structure:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [customer_id] => 962
                [event_id] => 1
                [score] => 356
                [point] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [customer_id] => 962
                [event_id] => 1
                [score] => 356
                [point] => 1
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [customer_id] => 962
                [event_id] => 2
                [score] => 356
                [point] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [customer_id] => 962
                [event_id] => 2
                [score] => 356
                [point] => 1
            )
    }
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [customer_id] => 962
                [event_id] => 3
                [score] => 356
                [point] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [customer_id] => 962
                [event_id] => 3
                [score] => 356
                [point] => 1
            )
    }
```

Comment: "the total"... WHAT total? there are no `total` keys in that array anywhere.

Comment: *add a knew element show the total* Where ? Show us an example of an output.

Comment: Show us your required output sample.

Comment: Sorry, long night. I wanted to see if it was possible to sum the "score" fields per customer and then add the total as a new element to the current array.

Comment: That should be pretty easy using for example a nested `foreach` loop. What do you have so far?

Comment: " then add the total as a new element to the current array" Which array, the inner one, or the parent array? Does the whole parent array just contain one customer? Perhaps edit your question with your expected output

Comment: Yes, I will do that asap.

Comment: Why you must insert the total into the same array ? Can't you add an array `total` that contains the `customer_id` and its total ?

Comment: You example array has all the same customer_ids's - is that a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a couple of nested foreach loops, and a temporary array:

```
$temp=array();
foreach($data as $element)
    foreach($element as $child)
        $temp[$child['customer_id']] = isset($temp[$child['customer_id']])?$temp[$child['customer_id']]+$child['score']:$child['score'];

foreach($data as &$element)
    foreach($element as &$child)
        $child['total']=$temp[$child['customer_id']];
```

Live example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/HkNF67

**Note** this was based on you wanting to total the scores, if you want to total points instead you can just substitute `$child['score']` for `$child['point']`

Answer (score 0):

You will need two steps: First walk over the array and calculate the total points per `customer_id`. Then walk over it again and attach the `total_point` to each customer:

```
// Step 1

function reduce_points_total($carry, $item) {
    if (is_array($item)) {
        if (isset($item['customer_id']) && isset($item['point'])) {
            if (!isset($carry[$item['customer_id']])) $carry[$item['customer_id']] = 0;
            $carry[$item['customer_id']] += $item['point'];
        } else {
            $carry = array_reduce($item, reduce_points_total, $carry);
        }
    }
    return $carry;
}

$points_total = array_reduce($array, reduce_points_total, array());

// Step 2

function insert_points_total(&$item, $key, $points_total) {
    if (is_array($item)) {
        if (isset($item['customer_id']) && isset($points_total[$item['customer_id']])) {
            $item['points_total'] = $points_total[$item['customer_id']];
        } else {
            array_walk($item, insert_points_total, $points_total);
        }
    }
}

array_walk($array, insert_points_total, $points_total);
```

The recursive `array_reduce` in Step 1 calculates the `$points_totale`. It generates an array:

```
Array
(
    [962] => 4
    [963] => 3
)
```

An recursive `array_walk()` in Step 2 inserts these numbers to the main `$array`.

Here you find a running demo: https://eval.in/200799